# How to save decision tree trained model in ignite?

Tags: java, ignite

Following is the piece of code i'm trying to save my model. But i'm unable to find saveModel() API functionality to store the model.

```
// Create classification trainer.
DecisionTreeClassificationTrainer trainer = new DecisionTreeClassificationTrainer(10, 0.1);

// Train decision tree model.
Model mdl = trainer.fit(
    ignite,
    dataCache,
    featureExtractor,
    labelExtractor
);
Exporter<DecisionTreeNode, String> exporter = new FileExporter<>();
**((DecisionTreeNode)mdl).saveModel(exporter, filePath);**
```

Comment: The `Model` interface extends from the `Serializable` interface. Can you save and load it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every classification algorithm(KNN, ANN, KMeans...) implements exportable modelFormat interface except decision tree, so in this case we can save it with ModelsComposition (which is true for decision tree scenario)

Exporter exporter = new FileExporter<>();

((ModelsComposition) mdl).saveModel(exporter, filePath);